# Printing in WPF similar to Winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, memory, printing

Below is the process I worked in Windows forms for printing.
I used PrintDocument class. It contains PrintPage event and I used that to draw the graphics of what I need to print and obtained the result successfully as I expected.

Below is the code:

```
public PrintDocument Printing
{
   m_printDocument = new PrintDocument();
   m_printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(OnPrintPage);
}
```

The code for OnPrintPage as follows:

```
protected virtual void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
 {
      //Image img = I have the things to be printing in the form of image.
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(0,0));
 }
```

In WPF:

I am working with Fixed document and by using the below code I can print

```
PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();
print.PrintDocument(FixedDocument.DocumentPaginator, "Print") //Where Fixed document contains the data to be printed.
```

This results is insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
But I got Fixed document without any problem.
Any solutions ...?
I hope the similar thing as like Windows form would be there in WPF too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to get this when my pages contained lots of visual elements (drawings/images/ complex diagrams). Instead of printing the complete document at once (which can lead to out of memory)

```
print.PrintDocument(FixedDocument.DocumentPaginator, "Print")
```

I printed one of its page.

```
 PrintQueue selectedPrntQueue = printDialog.PrintQueue;     
 XpsDocumentWriter writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(selectedPrntQueue);
 SerializerWriterCollator collator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();
 collator.BeginBatchWrite();
 var paginator = FixedDocument.DocumentPaginator;
 FixedPage fixedPage = paginator.GetFixedPage(printedPageCount)
 ContainerVisual newPage = new ContainerVisual();
 Size sz = new Size(pageSize.Height.Value, pageSize.Width.Value);
 fixedPage.Measure(sz);
 fixedPage.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), sz));
 fixedPage.UpdateLayout();
 newPage.Children.Add(fixedPage);
 collator.Write(newPage);
```

I had to do GC after printing few pages (my magic number was 10). 
You may need to tweak the this up to your requirement.

Comment: This prints directly to the default printer. Is there a way to ask me to choose printer.?